# Cannot gather 2 XML responses from Scatter-Gather

Tags: java, mule, dataweave

I am trying to process two HTTP requests (XML returns) using Scatter-Gather component in Mule. Coming out of Scatter-Gather the payload is:

payload (mimeType="*/*" encoding="UTF-8")
Object = java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList containing 2:

- [1] org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream
- [2] org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream

I have tried:
1. Transform Message
2. Combine Collections
3. Combine Collections -> Transform Message

I have NOT been able to obtain a successful XML message from the 2 called flows in Scatter-Gather. I do know that at breakpoints on the components, the payload is (mimeType="*/*) and in fact I see this as an INFO log message in the console when the firing HTTP request is made to start my Scatter-Gather flow.

Can anyone suggest a way to obtain my XML output? The scatter-gather flow requests return the same XML/XSD from separate Mule apps. I have a common data model (CDM) that I want to use in the end to bring these requests into and also use Message Enrichment to help with the other parts.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should transform to XML within each scatter gather route, then out of there you'll have a collection with both XMLs instead of the InputStreams.
HTH

Comment: I've been doing that today using Dataweave components but ... I can't get past " Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'. My mimeType always says */* and I think the transform from SimpleDataType is JSON, hence the bracket found for the array. Not sure, but I get the exception and error (above) using Transform Message components (output:application/xml) on each scatter-gather path.

Comment: My mimeType is always asterisk/asterisk and I can't figure out how to change that.

Comment: Transformer           : ObjectToByteArray{this=4744e71b, name='_ObjectToByteArray', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.io.Serializable, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}

Comment: Can you log the HTTP responses to make sure what data you are receiving?

Comment: I was successful in getting "an" XML output, however it was only the output of one of the scatter-gather requests. I think it's because the schemas are the same 99% from each. In the root tag e.g. type="home" or "auto" in the other request. I am now getting XML but only the request from type="home". It's easy enough for me to add a type column to the database and send 100% exact schemas from the scatter-gather requests so I'm going to try that today.

Comment: I'm getting exactly one request's worth of XML. The other request is successful but I think it's because I use an attribute in the root tag and it's different on the other request. I'm going to add a column and remove the need for the attribute and if I'm correct, this will be good info to remember. Also I may ask if attributes in the root tags "should" be allowed.